# Visual Studio Express 2015 for Web - IIS/Developer Web Server

Tags: iis, visual-studio-express

I have two questions about servers of VS Express 2015 for Web

First at all, it's dissappeared an option for change from IIS server to native Developer Web Server from project options. Is it due to Express version or could I install it?

Second problem is with URLs of IIS server. I didn't change default settings but my url:

> http://localhost:51734/PROJECT_FOLDER/SUBFOLDER/PAGE.aspx

trims into

> /SUBFOLDER/PAGE.aspx

I know somewhere in IIS settings I can customize the URL, but I want my URL without changes.

EDIT: I should say it trims SOMETIMES into that URL

Comment: You will have to provide more info on the second question such as screen shots. For the first, ASP.NET Development Server is dead and no longer provided.

Comment: Screenshot says same as I do. Normally my url should look for example like: http://localhost:52185/MYPROJECT/SUBFOLDER/PAGE.aspx?ReturnURL=~/SUBFOLDER/OTHER_PAGE.aspx, but first trim is this: http://localhost:52185/SUBFOLDER/PAGE.aspx?ReturnURL=~/SUBFOLDER/OTHER_PAGE.aspx, and after that, after redirect sometimes dissappears "localhost" too (because project name is not even in ReturnURL) and it cause browser error, that "This page is not accessible... ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED"